# How to auto-give role when someone is playing game? V12 discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently decided to upgrade my discord js library to v12.
I wanted to when someone turns on the game (Golf With Your Friends) he gets a role. But I can't program it in discord js v12. Can you help me?
Here is my code in v11:

```
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    let guild = newMember.guild;
    let playRole = guild.roles.get("633589794357641235");
    if (!playRole) return;

    if (newMember.user.presence.game && newMember.user.presence.game.name === "Golf With Your Friends") {
        newMember.addRole(playRole);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a guide from discordjs.guide on updating from v11 to v12:

https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache

You can also check the official docs here:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate

Firstly they updated the parameters to `oldPresence` and `newPresence`,

So:

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  //....
}
```

Second they changed the collection from `guild.roles` to `guild.roles.cache`:

```js
const playRole = guild.roles.cache.get("633589794357641235");
```

Third your if statement uses `newMember.user.presence` which now is just `newPresence`, game has been modified into an `Activity` class, and there is no more `<Presence>.game`, so you will have to loop over the `<Presence>.activites` array:

```js
if (newPresence.find(e => e.name === "Golf With Your Friends")) {
  //...
}
```

And lastly they moved `<GuildMember>.addRole` to `<GuildMember>.roles.add`:

```js
newPresence.member.roles.add(playRole);
```

Full code:

```js
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let guild = oldPresence.guild;
    //guild.roles => guild.roles.cache
    let playRole = guild.roles.cache.get("633589794357641235");
    if (!playRole) return;

    if (newPresence.find(e => e.name === "Golf With Your Friends")) {
        newPresence.member.roles.add(playRole);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('bot sucessfully logged')
})

client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let guild = oldPresence.guild;
    //guild.roles => guild.roles.cache
    let playRole = guild.roles.cache.get("837208147302154252");
    if (!playRole) return;

    if (newPresence.find(e => e.name === "Testing")) {
        newPresence.member.roles.add(playRole);
    }
});

client.login("token")
```

error is if (newPresence.find(e => e.name === "Testing")) {
^

TypeError: newPresence.find is not a function